# I´m having problems with this Context Free Grammar

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

I am not able to convert the following language to a Context Free Grammar. The major problem is how to pump both "sides" of the word to obtain same number of 0s and 1s, but, without creating a series of 01010101.

$$L=\{0^{r_1}1^{s_1}0^{s_2}1^{r_2}\mid r_1+r_2 = s_1 + s_2,\ \ r_1,r_2,s_1,s_2 > 0\}$$

Can someone explain a solution to me?

Comment: `the word` is not restricted to terminal symbols.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18524/755

Comment: I mistake mayor with major, sorry

Comment: Here is a similar question, [context-free grammar for $L = \{ a^nb^mc^kd^l | n + k = m + l, (n,m,k,l) \in \mathbb{N} \}$](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/77341/cfg-problem-solved-with-pda-looking-for-alternative-solution). You can learn from the answer to it.

Comment: Ty, I´ll take a look.

Comment: I think that´s it, I use the same idea to my problem and I´ve solved half of it, ty, post it as an answer if you want.